# try catch not working in swift

Tags: xcode, swift2

This should be simple and obvious but try catch in swift2 frustrating me. here is my code.

```
@IBAction func btnAdd_TouchDown(sender: AnyObject) {

        do  { try AddNewNotesToList() } catch{

            if(Ex.UnknownError != "")
            {
                Error(Ex.UnknownError)
            }
        }
    }



func AddNewNotesToList() throws
    {
        var obj: TreatmentNotesDTO = TreatmentNotesDTO()
        obj.therapist_id = Int(TherapistId)! // getting error here
        return
    }
```

Error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Debugger should go to catch but its breaking up. I am from c# and just started swift2. Any help

Comment: To catch an error the target function must throw one. Read the chapter "Error Handling" in the Language Guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42-ID508

Comment: Didn't got you properly, Any code you can show?

Comment: I added the `throws` in function but still not working. I don't want manual defining the error. Swift should automatically pick the error like c#,javascript etc lang.

Comment: In Swift you have to define the error when using `try - catch`. It might be easier just to check the result of the `Int` initializer with optional binding as described in the answer of Qbyte

Comment: Yes got you now, But it seems very annoying, If i had 100 'variable' in `AddNewNotesToList ` then i need to create throw function for all 100 `variable`. There must be some short way

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use `guard` to catch such errors:

```
guard let therapistID = Int(TherapistId) else {
    print(TherapistId + " cannot be converted to an Int")
    return
    // or mark function as throws and return an error
    throw NSError(domain: TherapistId + " cannot be converted to an Int", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
}
obj.therapist_id = therapistID
```

Note that `Int(TherapistId)!` doesn't throw an error with `throws`. It is a `fatal error` which stops program execution.